# Parse unix time with pd.to_datetime and datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to parse a Unix timestamp using `pd.to_datetime()` vs. `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp()`, but their outputs are different. Which one is correct?

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

ts = 1674853200000
print(pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='ms'))
print(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1e3))

>> 2023-01-27 21:00:00
>> 2023-01-27 13:00:00
```

Comment: I don't reproduce your output, both give me `2023-01-27 21:00:00`

Comment: @mozway check the time zone of the machine you run this code on. Is it UTC or UTC+0 ? In contrast to pandas (numpy) datetime, vanilla Python naive datetime defaults to *local time*.

Comment: @FObersteiner no it's not UTC

Comment: @mozway I've added an illustration with some code. If you cannot reproduce that on your machine, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to pandas (numpy) datetime, vanilla Python datetime defaults to local time if you to not specify a time zone or UTC (= use naive datetime). Here's an illustration. If I reproduce your example in my Python environment, I get

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pandas as pd

# ms since the Unix epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC
unix = 1674853200000 

dt_py = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix/1e3)
dt_pd = pd.to_datetime(unix, unit="ms")

print(dt_py, dt_pd)
# 2023-01-27 22:00:00 # from fromtimestamp
# 2023-01-27 21:00:00 # from pd.to_datetime
```

Comparing the datetime objects with my local time UTC offset, there's the difference:

```py
# my UTC offset at that point in time:
print(dt_py.astimezone().utcoffset())
# 1:00:00

# difference between dt_py and dt_pd:
print(dt_py-dt_pd)
# 0 days 01:00:00
```

To get consistent results between pandas and vanilla Python, i.e. avoid the ambiguity, you can use aware datetime:

```py
dt_py = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix/1e3, tz=timezone.utc)
dt_pd = pd.to_datetime(unix, unit="ms", utc=True)

print(dt_py, dt_pd)
# 2023-01-27 21:00:00+00:00 
# 2023-01-27 21:00:00+00:00

print(dt_py-dt_pd)
# 0 days 00:00:00
```

Comment: Ah ha, the timezone! Love your answer, so concise and straight to the point. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The main difference between them is that ***pd.to_datetime()*** is more flexible and can handle missing input data, while ***dt.datetime.fromtimestamp()*** assumes the input timestamp is in the local time zone. Generally, the choice of which one to use depends on the requirements of your use-case.